# Indentation defined via preferences and via GUI

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm trying to understand how ST's indentation defined via `"transtate_tabs_to_spaces"` is different from indentation defined via GUI (bottom right corner of the window).

Step 1. Add this preferences:

```
"draw_white_space": "all",
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
```

Step 2. Ensure you have this:

[image]

And not this:

[image]

Step 3. Create new file inside ST with single line and press `Ctrl-]` (on Windows). It will be indented with 4 spaces - exactly as the user expected:

[image]

Step 4. Now, turn off the check mark in front of `Indent Using Spaces` in the GUI:

[image]

And then, reproduce step 3. You will see, that text was indented with a tab, instead of spaces, despite you still have `"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true` in your preferences.

[image]

So, it looks that ST have 2 ways to control indentation - via `translate_tabs_to_spaces` setting and via GUI, and GUI have precedence.

- Is everything correct in my description?
- And is there a way to reliably enforce spaces, which will not be overwritten by GUI? (For example, it could be used `expand_tabs` command on save, but probably there exists another ways to handle this issue?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your premise is essentially correct, but there is something happening behind the scenes that you may not be expecting.

The setting `translate_tabs_to_spaces` tells Sublime that whenever anything tries to insert a literal tab character, it should expand the tab to some number of spaces instead, with the number of spaces coming from the `tab_size` setting.

There is only one setting that controls this, but the menu item that you see in the indentation menu (either from the button in the status line or in `View > Indentation` in the main men) uses the `toggle_setting` command.

For example if you use `View Package File` from the command palette to view `Default/Indentation.sublime-menu` (the definition for the menu that pops up in the status bar), the first entry in the menu item is this one (reformatted here to not be one long line):

```json
{ 
    "command": "toggle_setting", 
    "args": {"setting": "translate_tabs_to_spaces"}, 
    "caption": "Indent Using Spaces", 
    "checkbox": true 
},
```

The `toggle_setting` command changes the setting in a `view` specific way; that is, it modifies the setting in the buffer that you're currently editing, but not in your actual preferences file.

If you consult the [documentation on settings](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/settings.html), you can see that buffer specific settings are the last item in the list of potential places for settings to come from, which makes them take precedence over everything else. A buffer specific setting only persists while you have the file open; if you close the file and re-open it, the original preference will re-assert itself.

You can verify this in both of your cases above by opening the Sublime console with <kbd>Ctrl+`</kbd> or `View > Show Console` and entering the following python command while you have each of the two files focused:

```python
view.settings().get("translate_tabs_to_spaces")
```

If you do this, you'll see that it returns `True` when the checkbox is checked and `False` when it's not.

Generally speaking the biggest vector for problems when it comes to the `translate_tabs_to_spaces` setting is the `detect_indentation` setting, which defaults to `true` unless you turn it off.

When that setting is turned on, every time a file is loaded Sublime automatically runs the command associated with the `Guess Settings From Buffer` command in the indentation menu. That can cause the indent settings you've chosen to change from what you expected them to be.

Realistically, with the appropriate settings set it should work the way you want as long as you don't purposefully change the setting by using the menu item.

In theory a simple plugin could be employed to alter what that menu item does so that it would toggle the setting globally instead of in the current buffer only, but in that case every other file you have loaded would suddenly have it's setting changed, which is arguably much worse.

Comment: For further readers: If you open console and launch `view.settings().get("translate_tabs_to_spaces")` in it, you will see `True` or `False` (of course), but then, if you try to enable/disable check mark _while your caret is still inside console input box_, you will get the same output as was your first. For example, if your first output was `True`, you could enable/disable check mark, but you will always have `True`. This is because you actually have changed the check mark for console view, instead of changing it for your main view.

Comment: To get the correct test: 1. Launch the command in console. See the current output (`True`), 2. Then put your caret into file. Enable/Disable check mark, 3. Put your caret back into console and repeat command. You will see that now you have different output (`False`) - exactly as it should be.